# What type of bird makes the birdsong in the episode Amy's Choice?

Tags: doctor-who, amy-pond

In season 5, episode 7 **[Amy's Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amy%27s_Choice_%28Doctor_Who%29)**

The Doctor and his companions switch between alternate "realities".  Just before each switch they hear birdsong.

What sort of birdsong is that?

I ask because this spring I am hearing that exact birdsong and it makes me wonder about the nature of reality :D

Comment: I just rewatched that episode a few days ago and I'm hearing the exact same chirps _everywhere_ now, too! The wife and I looked at each other, smiled and "fell asleep"!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm struggling to find a canon confirmation but the birdsong clip in [Amy's Choice](https://youtu.be/xutztW73I6c?t=47s) sounds very much like a robin.

Given that you appear to be in the US, what you're hearing is possibly some kind of grosbeak or vireo, both of which are said to have [similar calls](http://www.larkwire.com/library/bird-sounds/group/robin-like-east-int) to the European Robin

Comment: I know right! I hear the exact song every morning. No not similar to the Robin above. It is exactly the same as the episode.

Answer (score 3):

I hear the exact song every morning. It is not similar to [the Robin above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86262/58193), but is exactly the same as the episode.

However, the [Grosbeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grosbeak) is probably a hit. I have seen these at our bird feeder and this recording sounds really close:

I just finally caught sight of the bird singing.  Turns out it is a house wren!

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your own posts rather than creating a separate answer for it. This itself is a nice answer but note I have edited in the parts of your other answer so this makes sense on its own rather than referring back to it.

Comment: Note if I've misinterpreted your previous answer in my edit please feel free to edit your post to change it.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me that it's a Wrens call that has been edited/looped/reversed

Comment: This appears to be little more than a guess